# Command Line to Open specific Outlook 365 Calendars

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, script, exchange, calendar

Questions:

1. How can I open a specific outlook calendar via a command line?
2. How do I find the values to use in the `/select` switch?

Work already done:

- Using `"c:\program files\microsoft office\root\office16\outlook.exe" /select outlook:calendar` opens the default calendar, however I would like to open outlook to another of my calendars.

Notes:

- Calendar "1" is my default calendar, but I would like to be able to open to one of the other calendars.

[image: Calendar Sidebar - Outlook]

Answer (score 1):

I try below to point out a direction for opening Outlook to
a specific calendar, but cannot get down to details or guarantee
a solution.

The Outlook command line is more general than is described in the
documentation:

```
outlook.exe /select outlook:{ENTRYID}
```

This could work for a specific calendar, but you will need to find
the EntryID of this calendar.

The tool for that is probably
[mfcmapi](https://github.com/microsoft/mfcmapi).

You may find information on using mfcmapi inside the following
articles:

- [Shared calendar appears in delegate's Online Archive folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/troubleshoot/calendars/shared-calendar-in-delegate-online-archive)
- [Troubleshooting calendar items](https://ingogegenwarth.wordpress.com/2015/05/01/troubleshooting-calendar-items/)
- [Backing up Calendar views and then restoring them](https://rajivpasalkar.wordpress.com/2018/07/25/backing-up-calendar-views-and-then-restoring-them/)

Comment: Ok. I will look into this. Thank you for the guidance.

Answer (score 0):

1.In Outlook, there is no direct command line to open a particular calendar item. The following article summarizes some command-line operations for your reference:https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/how-to-use-outlooks-command-line-switches/.

2.The values to use in the /select switch are the names of the Outlook folders that you want to open. For example, if you want to open the Inbox folder, you can use the following command: `outlook /select outlook:inbox`

If you want to open a subfolder or a custom folder, you can use the full folder path separated by slashes. For example, if you want to open a folder named Projects under the Inbox folder, you can use the following command: `outlook /select outlook:inbox/projects`

You can also use the folder ID instead of the folder name, if you know it. The folder ID is a unique identifier for each folder in Outlook. You can find the folder ID by using the [MFCMAPI tool] or by using PowerShell. For example, if you want to open the Calendar folder using its ID, you can use the following command:
`outlook /select outlook:{ID}`